# Plural von "Szenario"? Szenarien oder Szenarios?

Tags: word-choice

Welches ist die korrekte Form? Ich habe es ursprünglich als "Szenarien" gelernt, meine Rechtschreibprüfung will mich aber überzeugen, daß Szenarios korrekt(er?) sei. Ein alter Duden kennt nur "Szenarios". Wurde es mir falsch beigebracht?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alle gängigen Wörterbücher sind sich einig, dass in heutigem Deutsch sowohl *"Szenarios"* als auch *"Szenarien"* richtige Pluralformen von *"Szenario"* sind. Allerdings erhält man keine Hilfe, welche der beiden Formen nun die "richtigere" ist, oder ob es gar Bedeutungsunterschiede gibt. Man muss also ein wenig in der Etymologie des Wortes graben, um vielleicht weiterzukommen.

Ursprünglich gab es nur die *"Szenerie"* mit ähnlicher Bedeutung. In der Theaterwissenschaft wurde aber manchmal auch von einem vom lateinischen *["scaenarium"](http://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/scaenarium-uebersetzung.html)* hergeleiteten *"[Szenar, Szenarium](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS57668)"* gesprochen. Erst [seit den 70er Jahren](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Szenarium,%20Szenario&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=) taucht neuerdings auch zunehmend der Begriff *"Szenario"* auf, bei dem es sich wohl um den Dativ oder Ablativ des *"scaenarium"* handeln dürfte, oder aber auch um einen Anglizismus hergeleitet von *"[scenario](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11775/what-is-the-plural-of-scenario)"*. Für letzteres spräche neben dem Entstehungszeitraum auch, dass der Plural *"Szenarios"* als grammatikalisch korrekt angesehen wird.

Nimmt man aber das usprüngliche *"Szenarium"* zur Grundlage, dann würde das Wort tatsächlich in Analogie zu anderen Lehnwörter mit Suffix *-ium* im Plural *"Szenarien"* lauten (vgl. *Aquarien, Studien,...*).

Tatsächlich findet man in redigierten Tageszeitungen (inklusive [Bild](http://www.bild.de)!) auch fast ausschließlich die Verwendung von *"Szenarien"* und nur selten *"Szenarios"* im Plural (beachte hierbei auch, dass natürlich der Genitiv von *Szenario* unstrittig *Szenarios* sein muss).

Comment: Daß man plötzlich einen anderen lateinischen Kasus hernimmt, halte ich für sehr unwahrscheinlich. Eher steckt das Italienische dahinter, wo _-o_ die regelmäßige Fortsetzung von lateinisch _-um_ und _-us_ ist: _scenario_; sei es nun direkt oder über das Englische.

Comment: Andere Beispiele mit „italienischstämmigem“ _-o_: _Mafioso_ (gern auch _ein Mafiosi_, _mehrere Mafiosos_ oder diverse andere Kombinationen), _Motto_, _Ghetto_, _Cello_; diverse Namen wie _Marco_.

Comment: Hmhm … nochmal zum Anglizismus: Mag durchaus sein, aber der _s_-Plural ist kein Argument dafür. _-s_ ist nämlich die deutsche Standardpluralendung für Wörter, die auf unbetonten ‚richtigen‘ Vokal (nicht Schwa) enden, wie zum Beispiel _Uhu_, _Oma_, _Auto_. Der italienische Plural auf _-i_ ist nie so richtig heimisch geworden, deshalb gibt es z.B. auch bei _Motto_, _Mafioso_, _Cello_ eine Tendenz zum _s_-Plural.

Comment: Ich denke, die Etymologie bringt uns hier nicht weiter in der Frage, was "richtiger" ist. Schon die Frage scheint mir falsch gestellt. Es ist halt einfach beides richtig.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   ... doch kann man die Frage gewiss füglich dahingehend permutieren, dass man wissen will, welchen Eindruck man durch Verwendung der einen oder der anderen Form beim geschätzten Publico erzeugen werde.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ja, bestimmt.

Comment: Bei den Fundstellen in Zeitungen wirst Du aber im allgemeinen nur schwer sagen können, ob es der Plural von Szenario oder Szenarium ist.

Answer (score 5):

In älteren Duden-Büchern, wie z. B.

- Duden Band 1 – *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung,* 22. Auflage (2000)
- Duden Band 7 – *Fremdwörterbuch,* 7. Auflage (2001)

wurde als Plural von *Szenario* ausschließlich die Form *Szenarios* angegeben:

> **Sze|na̲|rio,** das; -s, -s (…)

In neueren Duden-Büchern, wie z. B.

- Duden Band 1 – *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung,* 25. Auflage (2009)
- Duden Band 7 – *Fremdwörterbuch,* 10. Auflage (2010)

findet man dagegen neben *Szenarios* auch die Nebenform *Szenarien:*

> **Sze|na̲|rio,** das; -s, -s, *auch* …ien (…)

Diese Änderung ist sicherlich eine Anpassung an den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch; denn damit ein Wort in den Duden kommt, muss es über mehrere Jahre hinweg in einer gewissen Häufigkeit in verschiedenen Textsorten auftreten.<sup>[[1]](http://www.duden.de/ueber_duden/wie-kommt-ein-wort-in-den-duden)</sup> Vermutlich gibt es aber (wie in anderen vergleichbaren Fällen) konservative Sprachpfleger, die diese Änderung kritisieren und ausschließlich *Szenarios* für standardsprachlich richtig halten.

Comment: Es wäre gut, wenn Du auch noch den Eintrag zu *Szenarium* erwähnen würdest.

Answer (score 3):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Szenario) und [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Szenario) kennen sowohl "Szenarios" als auch "Szenarien".

Answer (score 2):

*Szenarien* ist schriftlich geläufiger ([siehe Statistik hier](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Szenarien,Szenarios&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)). Vermutung: Die Leute sagen vielleicht eher *Szenarios,* weil prägnante Wörter wie *Radio, Video, Mario* in der Mehrzahl *s* anhängen.

Comment: Kürzer und weniger höflich: Leute sagen Szenarios, wenn sie es nicht besser wissen. Oder günstigstensfalls, wenn sie es zwar besser wissen, jedoch fürchten, ob ihres Besserwissens von der wenigerwissenden Umwelt gedisst zu werden. (Na gut, *kürzer* war das jetzt auch nicht.)